# Determine indices of maximum values of clusters in a vector

Tags: matlab

I have a vector lets's say `A` of size `100x2`. The values of the first column of `A` ranges from 1 to 8. And the values of the second colomn are just random numbers. So, the first column is like an identification of a cluster number. What I want to do is, I want to get the index of the rows of the maximum 8 values in the second column but who are the largest in each cluster. So that the result will be the largest 8 indices of each cluster, this means that those largest 8 may be not the largest in the whole vector, because may be cluster one has three from the top, but because I only take one from each cluster only the biggest of them will be taken.

Please advise how this can be done in matlab and let me know if any more details needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**`accumarray`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with a custom function:

```
%// example data, second columns are random numbers between 0 and 1 
A = [ randi(8,100,1), rand(100,1) ]

maxima = accumarray( A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @max)
```

It will return all the maxima for each cluster but not their indices.

---

To get the indices of the maxima you'd need the second output of the `max` function, which I don't know if it is possible to get when used with accumarray. But there is the following workaround:

```
idx = accumarray( A(:,1), A(:,2), [], @(x) find(A(:,2) == max(x)))
```

finally the output could look like:

```
output = [A(idx,1) idx A(idx,2)]

output =

    1.0000   29.0000    0.9319
    2.0000   18.0000    0.7177
    3.0000   81.0000    0.9554
    4.0000   72.0000    0.9127
    5.0000   55.0000    0.9984
    6.0000   27.0000    0.7809
    7.0000    4.0000    0.8598
    8.0000   14.0000    0.9946
```

First column the cluster number, second the index of each maximum and third its value.

Comment: but how to get the index of the rows of those values in matrix `A` ?

Comment: I want to get a list of the index of those values in vector `A` like for example those 8 values, are located in rows 10,34,45,52,55,57,86,87

Comment: @user1460166 have a look at my edit. The rows in your last comment do not help without data

Answer (score 2):

To get the maxima and their locations, a simpler alternative is perhaps to use [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html):

```
As = sortrows([A (1:size(A,1)).']); %'// 3rd column keeps track of original order
ind = find(diff([As(:,1); inf])); %// find last occurrence of each column-1 value
maxValues = As(ind,2); %// maxima
maxIndices = As(ind,3); %// locations of maxima
```

Answer (score 2):

A [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) array helps to simplify this further yet:

```
s = sparse(1:size(A,1),A(:,1),A(:,2));
[m,ii] = max(s)
```

Example:

```
>> A = [randi(8,100,1) rand(100,1)]
>> s = sparse(1:size(A,1),A(:,1),A(:,2));
>> [m,ii] = max(s);
>> [ii; full(m)].'

ans =

   22.0000    0.9619
   68.0000    0.9561
   58.0000    0.9001
   14.0000    0.9133
   67.0000    0.9421
   53.0000    0.9027
   26.0000    0.8687
   18.0000    0.9961
```

Location and value of the maximum for each row are the columns in the result above.

Note: you can also construct `s` by:

```
s = spconvert([(1:size(A,1)).' A])
```